# A strange problem with WPF Window.Icon

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

I'm going to set `Window.Icon` property by using `ResourceDictionary` like below:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="Icon" Value="/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/Icon.ico" />
</Style>
```

Above Style wasn't change Icon of Window. However when i set Icon of Window directly, It is done correctly!

```
<Window Icon="/WpfApplication1;component/Resources/Icon.ico">
    //Content
</Window>
```

Note: `Build Action` of `Icon.ico` was set to `Resource` and `ResourceDictionary` also loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your style is not applied at all. You'll have to define your style in `app.xaml`, assign a key to it and set your windows style explicitly.
**EDIT:**
Goblin suggested another valuable solution, excerpt from his comment:
he could set the TargetType="{local:MainWindow}" where local is the namespace for WPFApplication1. The problem is that 'empty key'-application works only for the specified type - not descendants.

Comment: That is partially correct - he could set the TargetType="{local:MainWindow}" where local is the namespace for WPFApplication1. The problem is that 'empty key'-application works only for the specified type - not descendants.

Comment: @Goblin: thanks, didn't know that. I think, your comment should have been an answer.

Comment: @alpha-mouse - you can just add it as an alternative in your reply if you'd like - your answer will certainly work.

Comment: @Goblin: I think this should be TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}" Yes?